# Particles don't "bend" with displacement

Tags: modeling, particles

I have a soil particle system applied to a subdivided plane. This has displacement modifiers on it to make it look more bumpy and realistic.

As you can see, the particles just stay flat and as such there are some horrible empty patches. I would like the particles to sit on the surface of the bendy plane.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: a screenshot of your particle system's settings would help, too.
my guess is you have it set to "emitter", rather than "hair"?

Comment: That's actually not correct. I'm using hair emission with rendering as an object. I'll go ahead and attach the blend file now (2.8). EDIT: File too big, so screenshot attached.

Comment: Perhaps it's something to do with "use modifier stack"? I've tried this and it doesn't change anything here unless of course it's supposed to and this is a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things might come into account. The main two I can think of are:

**Wrong modifier order**

If you pout your displace modifier after the particles modifier, then it means that the particles are added when the mesh is flat, and only then the mesh is displaced. The right thing to do is first displace, then put the particles on it. Modifiers order matters.

[image]

**Use Modifier Stack**

If you use a subdivision modifier, you might check that in the particle's emission pannel.

Comment: Completely forgot about the modifier order, thanks.